# Having users with no emails set in Intercom service

Tags: ios, intercom, intercom-ios

I'm using intercom SDK and implement [Intercom registerUserWithEmail:...]; methods after user logs in or registers, also every launch i call:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    NSString *userEmail = [Utilities getUserEmail];
    if (lastUsedEmail) {
        [Intercom registerUserWithEmail: userEmail];
    }else
    {
        [Intercom registerUnidentifiedUser];
    }
}
```

Here is how it looks like in intercom web service:
[image: screenshot from intrecom]

Why these email fields are Unknown for particular users?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that `registerUnidentifiedUser` is not called? If it's called - that's the source of those email-less users.

Comment: Yes, that could be, but that's only a scenario when user sings up by facebook in the app and fb doesn't provide email, it's very rare case